# Set and pass variable (or similiar) when a feature is selected

Tags: wix, wix3.6

My question is: is it possible to set a (environment) variable or a property, only when a feature is selected? (for example in a feautre tree) What would be better, a variable, property...?

And how do I keep or pass the value, so I can check it in an ExePackage or MsiPackage with the InstallCondition?

I hope someone has an idea, because I tried every possible way which came to my mind, an none worked.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/04/09/feature-states-in-component-conditions/) describes the problem. One possibility might be to create a reg key component and add that to the feature you are trying to check. Then you could use that component as a test to see whether the feature is being installed. You could also query for that reg key to determine whether the feature was installed later in another installer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also thought about creating RegKeys, but I thought it would be a sloppy way to pass the information. But I tried this way, and it's definitly working =)